# ROS2-ROS1 Bridge Time Space

Tags: ros2, ros-noetic, multiple-machines

I have two PC:s in my configuration running on the same network.

**PC1:**

- ros2 foxy and ros1 noetic
- ros bridge
- realsense camera

**PC2:**

- ros1 noetic

The PC2 runs roscore, which PC1 transmits its camera stream to through the ros1_bridge.
In PC1 I printout the current timestamp and compare it to the timestamp from the image to get the delay of the transmitted image.

- Does the ros_bridge convert the timestamp from ROS2 to ROS1?
- Does ROS1 and ROS2 share the same time space, how is the synchronization achieved between them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For a multi-machine system, ros1 and ros2 assume that all machines have an OS that provides an accurate time-of-day clock. This is typically accomplished by running a Network Time Protocol daemon on every machine.